# Django: Get size of JSONField?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using Django + Postgres. I have a JSONField and I'd like to actually sort the JSONField by size of character count from largest to smallest. Is there a django native way to do this?

Comment: Internally a `jsonb` field is used, you can get the number of bytes used but it may be more complicated to get a character count

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many bytes it takes to store column:

for strings :

```
octet_length(string)
```

for ex max:

```
t=# with d(j) as (values('{"a":0}'),('{"a":null}'),('{"abc":0}'))
select j from d order by octet_length(j) desc limit 1;
```

[SQL String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

or

`pg_column_size(any) - Number of bytes used to store a particular value`

Getting row with largest json value is simply sorting by `pg_column_size(json_column) desc limit 1`